# Replace single placeholder with multiple values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a URL such as /api/employee/?/?. The ? in the URL should be replaced with values from an array such as [5, 71] so that it is converted to /api/employee/5/71.

This should be easy to implement, but just thought of checking whether there exists any function/library which achieves the desired effect.

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: Where are you doing the substitution? On a server? Client? Are you using any client-side frameworks? Angular routing does this very well, on the server side, just about every REST framework does this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure no `?` marks are in the url other than the ones to indicate the positions of replacements, you can use a loop with string replace..

```js
    var str = "/api/employee/?/?";
    var arr = [5, 71];
    
    arr.forEach(function(v){
        str = str.replace("?",v);
    });
    
    document.write(str);
```